# Fetch data from Firestore causes ordered data update incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list named 'guests', everything works good until I try to delete a guest from a specific table.
To delete, I fetch the table data from Firestore, filter the user and update it to Firestore again.
When I fetch the data from Firestore, the whole table is added to the ordered 'guests'.
It happens every time I get data and I can't understand how it gets updated because I simply filter the user and update it back to Firestore.

Everything works as expected except this issue, I'm able to delete it from 'tables' but 'guests' has this issue.

I tried few ways to get the data but same result.

Code:

```
onGuestDelete = async (id, tableId) => {
    const { firestore, auth } = this.props;
    const data = await firestore.get({ collection: 'guests', doc: auth.uid, subcollections: [{ collection: 'userTables', doc: tableId }] });
    const tableGuests = data.get('tableGuests').filter(guest => guest !== id);
    firestore.update({ collection: 'guests', doc: auth.uid, subcollections: [{ collection: 'userTables', doc: table.id }] }, { tableGuests });
}
```

After GET_SUCCESS is fired, you can see the last item of the array (8).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly,but try this

```
onGuestDelete = async (id, tableId) => {
    const { firestore, auth } = this.props;
    const data = await firestore.get({ collection: 'guests', doc: auth.uid, subcollections: [{ collection: 'userTables', doc: tableId }] });
     const tableGuests = data.get('tableGuests');
    const filteredGuests = tableGuests.filter(guest => guest !== id);
    firestore.update({ collection: 'guests', doc: auth.uid, subcollections: [{ collection: 'userTables', doc: table.id }] }, { filteredGuests });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have 'tables' and 'guests', each table contains guests ID, I want to delete a guest from specific table (delete his entry), it works but as you can see in the picture, the whole table is added to my ordered 'guests'. I hope I could explain it better now.

Comment: but this is what you specify in `fiirestore.update` to add filtered guests to your `guests/{userid}/userTables`

Comment: Yes and it works, but the 'guests' array comes from a different collection. I don't delete the guest, I delete its id from specific table. even if I comment everything below the firestore.get line and do nothing but get data, I will still have this issue... if you look at the picture, when GET_SUCCESS this occurs. I also have a different function where I fetch data from firestore and it does the same. my tables structure is: guests > user id > userTables > table id > tableGuests (array which contains all guests IDs on specific table) ||| and guests: guests > user id > userGuests

Comment: @danivegas still confused. So your problem is that guests are coming from the wrong collection ? Not from the one you would expect ?

Comment: It's coming from the right collection, but somehow with the list of the guests, the table I delete the guest ID from is added to that list. if you look at the picture, 0-7 are the guests (by id), and 8 is the table structure added to that list. the ID of item 8 belongs to a table, then you can see the tableGuests array inside (as mentioned before my tables structure). It's also hard for me to explain it because I really don't know how it's happening. I simply fetch data from firestore, really no idea..

Comment: ok, so you said if you remove everything from your code, and leave only `    const data = await firestore.get({ collection: 'guests', doc: auth.uid, subcollections: [{ collection: 'userTables', doc: tableId }] });` you will still have this behaviour ? another question, in your picture you have your redux store?

Comment: 1. You are correct. 2. The picture is from Redux DevTools

Comment: can you show your reducer and action for GET_SUCCESS ?

Answer (score 0):

In java, i just put the lists inside `onCreate()` **lifecycle** because lifecycle of `onStart()` always my lists ordered incorrectly. I don't know reactjs, but It might be the same for lifecycle of *reactjs*